# Stepper or helper to get on a stationary bike

Tags: workout, bicycling, exercise-equipment, equipment

Is there any kind of widget/equipment that helps people get on a bike who have trouble doing it on their own? Specifically stationary bikes. Looking for something simple and practical

Comment: How are you trying to get on the bike? Usually people step on one pedal, swing the other leg over onto the other pedal and then sit on the bike. Which step are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I think a simple step stool would be the most convenient, the issue is getting it out of the way of the pedals. Another possibility is a recumbent exercise bike, although... they're more expensive than a step stool and have a very different footprint.

Comment: @EricWarburton: it is for a more senior person that is kind of afraid to get on and stretch the leg and requires help

Comment: Is this for a specific model of stationary bike? Many, especially those not aimed at hardcore cyclists, have a step-through frame so there's no need to swing a leg over

Comment: @ChrisH: It is a low end stationary bike. The problem is not the leg over, but the saddle being relatively high

Comment: I see.  Some models have pedals further from the floor than real bikes, which might not help, and low-end ones can be too light to be as stable as I'd like

Comment: @ChrisH: it is stable and the pedals are ok, it is just that getting on the saddle is the issue. After the person is on the saddle there is no problem